# requireNotNull alternative in TypeScript for null safety

Tags: typescript

I recently started learning Kotlin and was wondering if TypeScript has a `requireNotNull` similar check or method?

I'm using a function getUserId() which either return a string or null.

```
const userId = getUserId()

MakeNetworkFetch(userId) // could be nulll

// Also at the moment I'm using this below code, which makes Typescript linter happy

MakeNetworkFetch(userId!!)
```

I tried searching for Double-bang after variable but could not find anything

Comment: `!` doesn't actually make it non-null, you're just telling the compiler you're certain it's going to be: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#non-null-assertion-operator-postfix-. All TypeScript type metadata is erased in compilation, it does not (cannot) do any runtime checking.

Comment: 1. `!!` is not a thing, it's just `!`. And all it does is lie to the compiler. 2. use the `strict` compiler option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kotlin's `requireNotNull` throws an `IllegalArgumentException` upon receiving a `null` value. In TypeScript, you could use an [assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) with [`NonNullable<T>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullabletype) to get the same behavior:

```
function requireNotNull<T>(value: T): asserts value is NonNullable<T> {
  if (value === null || value === undefined) {
    throw Error('Value is null');
  }
}
```

And then:

```
requireNotNull(userId);
makeNetworkFetch(userId); // type of userId inferred as string at compile time
                          // value of userId guaranteed to be non-null at runtime
```

The difference between this and the [non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator) (`userId!`), is that the *assertion function* remains present in the compiled JavaScript, so a `null` value will trigger the error, and will not be passed down to the method.